# mongodb group sum subdetail

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How can I make a general grouping by country with a SUM of Subdetailes/SubDocuments
How can I make a general grouping by country with a SUM of Subdetailes/SubDocuments

```
[{
      Country: 'USA',
      amount: 10,
      detailA: [{
        Country: 'USA',
        amount: 20,
      },{
        Country: 'MEX',
        amount: 20,
      },{
        Country: 'RUSK',
        amount: 30,
      }],
      detailB: [{
        Country: 'USA',
        amount: 90,
      }]
    },{
      Country: 'RUSK',
      amount: 30,
      detailA: [{
        Country: 'USA',
        amount: 50,
      },{
        Country: 'MEX',
        amount: 60,
      }],
      detailB: [{
        Country: 'MEX',
        amount: 10,
      }]
    }];
```

Output group by Country
USA  170
RUSK  60
MEX  90

Comment: You don't have a 'city' field; did you mean group by country?

Comment: Fixed question, thank you

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

### Code:

Using the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('countries').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'root.Country': '$Country',
            'root.amount': '$amount',
            detail: {
                $concatArrays: [ '$detailA', '$detailB'],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            detail: {
                $concatArrays: [ '$detail', ['$root'] ],
            },
        },
    },
    { $unwind: '$detail' },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$detail.Country',
            amount: { $sum: '$detail.amount' }
        }
    }
]);
```

### Explanation:

We need to bring all data to the same level, so we can then use the `$group` stage.
The shape of documents before that stage should be:

```
{ Country, amount }
```

In the first projection stage, the two `detailA` & `detailB` arrays are merged into `detail` array. Also the root fields `Country`, `amount` are grouped under `root` subdocument.

In the second projection, that `root` object is pushed into `detail` array.

The `detail` array is then 'unwinded' into individual documents.

Finally, we group by `Country` and sum the `amount`s.